# terraform conditionally create resource based on external data?

Tags: terraform

As part of a setup, I create TLS certs and store them in S3. Creating the certs is done via `external` data source that runs the command to generate the certs. I then use those outputs to create S3 bucket object `resource`s.

This works very well the *first* time I run `terraform apply`. However, if I change any other (non-cert) variable, resource, etc. and rerun, it reruns the `external` command, which generates a new key/cert pair, uploads them to S3, and breaks everything that already works.

Is there any way to create the resource conditionally? What pattern could I use to make the certs created only if they don't exist?

I did look at storing the generated keys/certs locally, but this is sensitive key material; I do not want it stored in local disk (and there are keys per environment).

Key/cert generation and storage:

```
data "external" "ca" {
  program = ["sh","-c","jq '.root|fromjson' | cfssl gencert -initca -"]
  #
  query = {root = "${ data.template_file.etcd-ca-csr.rendered }"}
  # the result will be saved in
  # data.external.etcd-ca.result.key
  # data.external.etcd-ca.result.csr
  # data.external.etcd-ca.result.cert
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "ca_cert" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id}"
  key = "ca.pem"
  content = "${data.external.ca.result.cert}"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "ca_key" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id}"
  key = "ca-key.pem"
  content = "${data.external.ca.result.key}"
}
```

Happy to look at using some form of conditional or entirely different generation pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that `external` is a data source, and thus Terraform expects that it is is read-only and side-effect-free. It re-runs data sources for every plan.

In order to do this via an external script, it would be necessary to use a resource provisioner to run the script *and* upload it to S3, since there is currently no `external` equivalent for *resources*, which *are* allowed to have side-effects, and provisioners are side-effect-*only* (that is, they can't produce results to use elsewhere in config.)

Another approach, though, would be to use Terraform's [built-in TLS provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/tls/index.html), which allows creation of certificates within Terraform itself. In this case it looks like you're trying to create a new CA cert and key, which could be done with [`tls_self_signed_cert`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/tls/r/self_signed_cert.html) like this:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "ca" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits = 2048
}

resource "tls_self_signed_cert" "ca" {
  key_algorithm   = "RSA"
  private_key_pem = "${tls_private_key.ca.private_key_pem}"

  # ... subject and validity settings, as appropriate

  is_ca_certificate = true

  allowed_uses = ["cert_signing"]      
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "ca_cert" {
  bucket  = "${aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id}"
  key     = "ca.pem"
  content = "${resource.tls_self_signed_cert.ca.cert_pem}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "ca_key" {
  bucket  = "${aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id}"
  key     = "ca-key.pem"
  content = "${resource.tls_self_signed_cert.ca.private_key_pem}"
}
```

The generated private key will be included in the state for use on future runs, so it's important to ensure that the state is stored securely. Note that this would also be true using the `external` data source, since data source results are also stored in state. Thus this approach is equivalent from the standpoint of where the secrets get stored.

I wrote more details about using Terraform for TLS certificate management in [an article on my website](http://apparently.me.uk/terraform-certificate-authority/). Its scope is broader than your requirements here, but may be of some interest.

Comment: Thanks Martin. In this case, that is exactly what I ended up doing. I cannot recall why we didn't start with the tls provisioner, but switched to it right at the time we wrote this question.

Comment: Either way, I guess the answer is, "no, you cannot have a conditional external data source." :-)

Comment: I think I would say rather "you can't use the external data source (safely) to create things"; you _can_ make decisions based on data source results, but the thing that tripped you up here was that your "data source" wasn't really a data source as Terraform thinks of it. At some point there might be an "external" resource that could do what you want here, but that'd be somewhat more complex and so far hasn't felt like a strong enough need to outweigh that complexity.

Comment: "You can make decisions based on data source results... wasn't really a data source as terraform thinks of it." Either way, it would have to give consistent results to be repeatable, would it not?

Comment: Right... it's a bit of a tautology to say it this way, but your data source should return a consistent value until it returning a new value is _desirable_. It's the responsibility of the data source itself -- or, in the case of `external`, the script it runs -- to provide whatever consistency is needed for a particular use-case. If your script were able to itself somehow remember what it returned on previous runs, that would work too.

Comment: "a bit of a tautology". It is such a pleasure to converse with an engineer with a broader education (and vocabulary). You just made my day.

Comment: "your data source should return a consistent value until it returning a new value is desirable. It's the responsibility of the data source itself". Got it. That makes sense; I believe I didn't think it all the way through. Doing so would require keeping tight track... which is what a provider does inherently, and provides a mechanism for indicating desire for change by tainting. Thanks again.